# Routing in CakePHP 1.3.3 has suddenly stopped working for one folder (beforeFilter issues?)

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, before-filter

We've had an application running on CakePHP 1.3.3 for years without a single hitch, but randomly it's started saying *"The requested address /task_scheduler/task_scheduler_mailouts was not found on this server."* - but it's only effecting this. Everything else running on that server (including other CakePHP applications) are fine.

When I enable debug in core.php, I get the following error messages:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: currentUser [APP\views\themed\default\layouts\default.ctp, line 50]

Error: The Behavior file app\models\behaviors\null.php can not be found or does not exist.

Error: Create the class below in file: app\models\behaviors\null.php

<?php
class NullBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

}
?>
```

All of the files are present in /task_scheduler/task_scheduler_mailouts and the currentUser variable is working without any problems on the other pages. currentUser is set in the `beforeFilter()` function in app_controller.php which as far as I know is used for every single page.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    ...
    $currentUser = ClassRegistry::init('WfEmployee')->getNetworkUser();
    ...
}
```

*(update)* if I hardcode the $currentUser variable I still get the not set notice. I don't think the beforeFilter() function is even running.

Any ideas as to what could have suddenly caused this error please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function beforeFilter() {
   parent::beforeFilter();
   $currentUser = ClassRegistry::init('WfEmployee')->getNetworkUser();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just added that line in, but it seems like the entire beforeFilter function isn't running :(

Comment: Have you tried using $this->loadModel('WfEmployee'); $this-> WfEmployee->getNetworkUser() ?

Comment: Thanks John, is that in my beforeFilter() function?

Comment: Yea, rather then using ClassRegistry::init('WfEmployee')->getNetworkUser();

Comment: Thank you, but nope - still nothing. Even if I just put in a simple `echo "Test";` in that function it still won't work.

Comment: Right ok, so firstly what you need to do is go into APP\views\themed\default\layouts\default.ctp and find were the value currentUser is getting echoed/set comment out the line for now and try running it again for debug purposes.

Comment: the second error sounds like your trying to calling behaviour file dynamically and the value is null hence why it's looking for  class NullBehavior extends ModelBehavior.

Comment: Thank you John - the currentUser was being echoed out in the beforeFilter() function rather than in the view file. I think it's dead :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but nope - no joy unfortunately. I think our plans are now to re-develop the system in something else :(

Comment: Why? Thats madness. It looks like you have a null value somewhere thats it. I would look a little further into the issue before taking them measures.

Comment: Also can you mark my comments up i need more point to comment on other issues.